# In Openlayers how do we print the frame area's in pdf, instead of all the canvas area and also how to print multiple frames as pages as a pdf?

Tags: angular, pdf, openlayers, polygon

In Openlayers how do we print the frame area's in pdf? instead of all the canvas area, and also how to print multiple pages / frames as pages as a pdf?

I tried the options,

this.workspaceFacade.map.once("rendercomplete", function ()), this function is taking more time in rendering the map and inside this fuction we are writing the code to print as pdf but to print multiple pages we are running a loop to print the frame in the map.once method but it is printing only

```
`async generatePDF() {
 try {
 let items = this.workspaceFacade.source.getFeatures();
 let finalOutput = [];
 let allExtent = [];
 let printArea = [];
  if (items.length > 0) {
    items.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
        item.setStyle(frameStylePrint());
        let extent = item.getGeometry().getExtent();
        allExtent.push(extent);
      }});
    }
    allExtent.map(async (item, index) => {
      this.workspaceFacade.map
        .getView()
        .fit(item, [1000, 900], { padding: [-10, 10, 0, -10] });
      let legendurl = this.LEGEND_URL;
      let htmlcont = this.htmlContent;
      let svgString, htmlButton, htmlLegend, htmlString;
      this.workspaceFacade.map.once("rendercomplete", function () {
        const mapCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        mapCanvas.width = 1000;
        mapCanvas.height = 900;
        const mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext("2d");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
          document.querySelectorAll(".ol-layer canvas, canvas.ol-layer"),

          function (canvas) {
            if (canvas.width > 0) {
              const opacity =
                canvas.parentNode.style.opacity || canvas.style.opacity;
              mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === "" ? 1 : Number(opacity);
              let matrix;
              const transform = canvas.style.transform;
              if (transform) {
                // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
                matrix = transform
                  .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
                  .split(",")
                  .map(Number);
              } else {
                matrix = [
                  parseFloat(canvas.style.width) / canvas.width,
                  0,
                  0,
                  parseFloat(canvas.style.height) / canvas.height,
                  0,
                  0,
                ];
              }
              // Apply the transform to the export map context
              CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
                mapContext,
                matrix
);
const backgroundColor =
canvas.parentNode.style.backgroundColor;
if (backgroundColor) {
mapContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
}
}
);
mapContext.globalAlpha = 1;
mapContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
mapCanvas.toBlob((blob) => {
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log("fourth", url, item);
htmlcont = `<div><img width="500" height="700" src="${url}" style="float:left; border: 1px solid black"></div>`;
console.log(htmlcont);
svgString = `<div>${htmlcont} </div>`;
htmlButton =
            `<div><input onclick="window.print()" id="button" type="button" value="Generate pdf" style="background-color: #5E7B8D;` +
            `color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 10px; position: relative;"></div>`; 
htmlLegend = `<div><img width="200" height="700" src="${legendurl}" style="float:left; border: 1px solid black"></div>`;
console.log(svgString);
htmlString = `<div id="planimetric">
${htmlButton}
${svgString}                                 
${htmlLegend}
</div>`;
printArea[index] = htmlString;
const planimetricView = window.open('', '_blank');
planimetricView.document.write(htmlString);
planimetricView.document.title = 'Preliminary Project - Secondary Network Elements';
planimetricView.document.close();
console.log(printArea);
});
});
// return printArea;
}
// )
);
// console.log(printArea1);
console.log(this.LEGEND_URL);
} catch (error) {
throw error;
}
}`
```

This is the print pdf method I written, here I'm getting list of polygon's from the vector source and printing them by making the extent in the map and fit the map with the polygon's extent.

Comment: You will need to use `await` so each feature is processed in sequence, also add new pages to the pdf before images https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-u30wlb?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks Mike for your help, this works. Can you pls suggest how to print the area inside a polygon as pdf ?

Comment: `fit` will fit a geometry or extent.  Do you want to clip to a geometry as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html ?

Comment: When i try giving the fit, it fits the canvas but in the output its printing areas outside the polygon as well

Comment: You can clip the output to the polygon https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-m8ty6q?file=/main.js

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the solution. It's working but the problem is I need to add some legends image so need to combine the canvas and add the legends, for that if I'm specifying some width and height it's not working as expected. Sorry for the repeated queries. I got struck from last two+ weeks on this area.

with the same code what I'm trying to do 
    mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 100, 1500,2040);                       
                        
                      }
                    }
                  );
                  mapContext.drawImage(img, 1700, 120,720,2040);

Comment: It might be easier to add the map and legend to the pdf separately..  jsPDF will allow more than one image on a page if you specify the position, width and height https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-addImage.htm

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-vr1fi9?file=/main.js this how I'm trying to achieve something but I will add a snapshot for what I'm getting in my local. in same forked one

Comment: If you do not want a full page map you should export at the size required instead of the page size.  Scaling down a page size export will distort the image.  The map canvas could then be drawn to a full page canvas together with other images such as legend https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-v4fv9s?file=/main.js or the map canvas and legend could added separately to the pdf https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-sz1vkv?file=/main.js  My link in previous comment was truncated, it should be https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage

Comment: Hi Mike, 

I tried with both the options, the printing of the two images is working fine but the drawn shape's extent is what not printing as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-edl0yn -> please refer to the images (Shape Drawn & pdf img). Width of the image is coming as expected but the height is taking extra not able to fix that. tried with padding or setting size etc. but nothing working as expected. Can you please update on this?